# Boost locale "Conversion failed" for gettext

Tags: c++, boost, gettext, mo, boost-locale

When I'm running this example code from [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/locale/doc/html/messages_formatting.html)

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::locale;
int main()
{
    generator gen;
    // Specify location of dictionaries
    gen.add_messages_path(".");
    gen.add_messages_domain("foo");
    // Generate locales and imbue them to iostream
    locale::global(gen("pl_PL"));
    cout.imbue(locale());
    // Display a message using current system locale
    cout << translate("Hello World") << endl;
}
```

I'm getting such exception: `std::runtime_error("Conversion failed")`

Problem only occurs when I use non ascii chars in translations.

Example content from my `.mo` file (command: `msgunfmt foo.mo`)

```
msgid "Hello World"
msgstr "ąę"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost is throwing this exception why try to convert translation.

To fix that just change generation to:
`locale::global(gen("pl_PL.UTF-8"));`